# Is it possible to present a UIViewController at a specific element in the hierarchy of presented screens for Google Admob policy compliance?

Tags: ios, admob

I have some freelance projects which use Google Admob. Now, the project manager told me that the projects are not in compliance with Google Admob's policy, apparently Google temporarily ceased serving ad to a specific project.

Here's an ideal flow that Google Admob wants (ref: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287):

[image]

That kind of implementation is quite not possible in iOS as far as I know. What currently the projects do is after the dismissal of the interstitial ad (via Admob Framework's delegate function, `interstitialDidDismissScreen` or `interstitialWillDismissScreen`), only then the next screen will be presented. In short, upon dismissal of the modally presented interstitial ad, the next screen is expected to be already and perfectly presented!

I've had multiple attempts to do that, only to result to this, of course, as we all know:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

And so my question is, is there a way to present a screen at the back of the presented screen?

I tried some other ways like removing animations, but the previous screen can still be seen. Simple project for those who want to try something:

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let vc1 = ViewController()
    let vc1navcon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = vc1navcon
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

**MultipleVCs.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .red

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "VC3", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.presentVc3))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

    }

    @objc func presentVc3() {
        let vc3navcon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController3())
        self.present(vc3navcon, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .green

    }
}

class ViewController3: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.backgroundColor = .blue

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "AddVC2", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.addVc2))
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton

        let barButton2 = UIBarButtonItem(title: "dismiss", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissVc3))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton2
    }

    @objc func dismissVc3() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {

        })
    }

    @objc func addVc2() {
        let vc2 = ViewController2()
        let vc2navcon = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc2)

        var viewControllers = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.childViewControllers
        viewControllers?.append(vc2navcon)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, these screens are in a `UINavigationController`. Therefore, from `ViewController1`, `present` the ad screen (most likely from the root to prevent it from being presented on a detached view controller). After the ad is presented, `push` to `ViewController2` from `ViewController1` with animation disabled (you will not see this as it is performed behind the presented view controller). And then when the ad is dismissed, the second view controller will be visible and the user can navigate backward as if the ad were never presented.

Comment: I get your idea, but the I need the VC2 to be presented modally, not pushed. Anyways, thanks for the answer, that gave me an idea though that perhaps I can just change all the screens' presentation style.

Comment: Can't you simply then `present` the second view controller with the ad superimposed over the view? And just use the dismiss animation to animate out the ad.

Comment: If they need to be distinct view controllers then `present` to a container view controller that has a `UINavigationController` in it that is already pushed to the ad. And just create a custom pop animation.

Comment: Thanks! I'm marking this an answer because.... there will be no other ways to do what I wanna do, but I'm going to use push rather than the present.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add the Admob view controller as a child view controller of the 2nd view controller. Once the 2nd view controller is pushed show the added child view controller.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html